# Prevent child component from triggering parent's onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

Using Material-ui in React, I want to have the `<IconButton>` to have one behavior with `onClick` (quickly add to the cart) and have the parent `<GridListTile>` to have a different `onClick` behavior (open the more info Dialog for that item).
My issue is that when I click on the `<IconButton>`, it does both actions at the same time (open the more info `Dialog` AND add to the cart.
Is there a way to have `<IconButton>` to not inherit the onClick from the parent component?

```html
<GridListTile key={tile.title}>
              <img
                src={`/${tile.img}`}
                alt={tile.title}
                onClick={handleClickOpen()}
              />
              <GridListTileBar
                title={tile.title}
                subtitle={<span>{tile.description}</span>}
                onClick={handleClickOpen()}
                actionIcon={
                  <Tooltip title="add to cart">
                    <IconButton
                      aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`}
                      className={classes.icon}
                      // onClick={handleClickOpen()}
                      onClick={() => {
                        dispatch({ type: "cart-increment" });
                      }}
                    >
                      <AddShoppingCartIcon />
                    </IconButton>
                  </Tooltip>
                }
              />
            </GridListTile>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the child handler, stop the event from propagating upward:

```
<IconButton
    aria-label={`info about ${tile.title}`}
    className={classes.icon}
    onClick={(e) => {
        e.stopPropagation();
        dispatch({ type: "cart-increment" });
    }}
```